# How to create relationship in ActiveRecord with Attributes in Join Table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 4 tables that look like the following:

```
User:
-id
-name
....

UserMapLayer:
-id
-auto_refresh
....

SystemLayer:
-id
-Name
-Path

UserLayer:
-id
-Name
-Path
```

I want to make a query through my user object that will give me all of the SystemLayer and UserLayer Objects in the following JSON structure

```
[{layer_id: UserMapLayer.id, name: **THE NAME FROM SystemLayer or UserLayer**, path: **THE PATH FROM SystemLayer or UserLayer**, auto_referesh: UserMapLayer.auto_refresh, source: *'SYSTEM' or 'USER' depending on the whether the record is from SystemLayer or UserLayer*}, {....}]
```

As you can see there I want to store some attributes in the UserMapLayer, but I don't want to replicate things like name, path, etc in the join table.

I am fairly new to Rails and ActiveRecord and have ZERO idea how to map the models to each other... here is my first pass...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_map_layers
end

class UserMapLayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_layers
  belongs_to :system_layers
end

class UserLayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_map_layers
end

class SystemLayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_may :user_map_layers
end
```

I am getting a plethora of different errors, but basically I just don't even know where to begin. I don't even know how to word a Google search for this type of problem. I can write this query in a straight SQL Union query, so I guess I am trying to replicate this in ActiveRecord.

I guess I am trying to do the following SQL query with ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT ul.name, ul.path, uml.auto_refresh from user_layers ul, user_map_layers uml where  
uml.layer_id = ul.id and uml.type = 'USER' and uml.user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT sl.name, sl.path, uml.auto_refresh from system_layers sl, user_map_layers uml where 
uml.layer_id = sl.id and uml.type = 'SYSTEM' and uml.user_id = 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Rails! It can be difficult to formulate a search query when you don't know what to call what you're looking for!

You are working with ActiveRecord Associations, so you'll want to be totally familiar with the [ActiveRecords Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide, and the related ones available in the "Guides Index" popup in the top navigation bar.  Stick to the official sources as much as possible because model definition and associations have evolved a lot through the years to increase security, and so old tutorials, examples, and even books will tell help you see how it used to be done, but can result in silent failures in today's controller actions.  These guides are really an excellent way to get the base understanding necessary to grow a real full-fledged app from.

Comment: Thanks for the link... it's good stuff. I am learning a lot from the docs! My question remains, "is what I am trying to do even realistic?"

Comment: Yes!  The key is in having the id of one model represented in a related table as something like main_model_id, because then ActiveRecord create the necessary accessor methods.  Do get to know the :has_many :through model because in so doing all the simpler correlations make better sense.

Comment: When you get beyond the ActiveRecord Association built-in abilities, know too that you can create your own methods on your models to do whatever else you need.  For instance, I often create two methods in my model files, one called "about" and the other called "description"  "About" is a class method that reminds me months after having been away from the project what this model is about, what's it's frailties are, etc.  "Description" is usually a console-report of the record collection I'm looking at.

Comment: Very nice advice... I am actually working now on a sample app to see if I have the gist! I'll update when I'm done! Thanks again!